# IE7 issue - <lable> pushes down next to <input>

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

For some reason, the text labels are being pushed down below the input tags. Here is the link: http://jurbank.com/lightning-grader/ the issue is at the very bottom of the page click "Get Started!"

Comment: Nice looking site @John.

Answer (score 0):

see if applying `float:left;` to your labels fixes it.

#### Edit

and the second radio button. It needs floated also.

PS nice site btw

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display:inline-block;` on both the `label` and the `input`.

To make it work in IE7, you also add

```
zoom: 1;
*display:inline;
```